# kohana 3.2 ORM find_all() with relationships

Tags: php, orm, kohana-3

I have 3 tables:

```
artists{id,name}
media{id,name,filename}
media_artists{artist_id,media_id}
```

I created the models with n-n relationships as described in the Kohana guide.

When I do in a controller:

```
$artist_view = new View('artists/profile'); 
$artist_id = $this->request->param('id');
$artist_view->artists = $artist_model->where('id', '=', $artist_id)->find();
$artist_view->media = $artist_model->media->find_all();
```

it works fine, and I can call the media entries related to this specific artist in my view.

Now I want to do a query where I get all the artists, with their related media, all in the same sql result, but I don't find the syntax.
This:

```
$artist_view->artists = $artist_model->order_by('name' , 'ASC')->find_all();
$artist_view->media = $artist_model->media->find_all();
```

doesn't work (doesn't throw an error but $artist_view->media is empty)

I've seen on some forums that something like this might work:

```
$artist_model->order_by('name' , 'ASC')->with('media')->find_all();
```

but it doesn't work for me.

In my view, at the end, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
foreach($artists as $a){
echo $a->name."<br />";
foreach($a->media as $m) echo $m->name."<br />";
echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the relationhsip in both models defined as follows:

```
// In artist model.
protected $_has_many = array(
        'media' => array('through' => 'media_artists'),
    );
// In media model.
protected $_has_many = array(
                'artists' => array('through' => 'media_artists'),
        );
```

It should work using (EDIT!):

```
$artists = ORM::factory('artist')->find_all();
foreach ( $artists as $artist )
{
    foreach ( $artist->media->find_all() as $m )
    {
        echo $m->name;
    }
}
```

I had the same problem in one of my projects and this solution works for me (Kohana 3.2.0).

Comment: That's what I have in my models... I read it in the documentation, so I had it already like that... I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Comment: the weird thing is that it works when I use ->find() on a single artist, but not with find_all()...

Comment: Hmmm, but one moment i have missed something (see edit): $artist->media->find_all() must be used. You have created the relationships in your SQL scheme (using foreign keys etc., when you are using MySQL)?

Comment: Yes. Actually I had just found the solution... the one you wrote in your edit! :) I'll accept your answer, thanks for your help!