# Kohana ORM - has many through models stored in parent model

Tags: php, orm, kohana

I had many problems with has_many-through relationships but finally I found nice example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8243274/938084) which solved most of my problems. However, according to code presented below I have couple questions.
firstly, code:

```
$artists = ORM::factory('artist')->find_all();
foreach ( $artists as $artist )
{
    foreach ( $artist->media->find_all() as $m )
    {
        echo $m->name;
    }
}
```

1) This example is probably controller. What if I want to store `media` in `$artists` to send one variable to view? Is it possible to store `media` as media property in artist object? (I mean for example `$artists[0]->media[0]->name`)
2) Is it possible to completely load `$artists` without this loop?

Comment: Why don't you create a function called `media($key = NULL)` in your artist object and let that return an array or single object? That would be simply `$artists[0]->media(0)->name` with `$key` being left out being the entire array, easy integration of caching would also be possible that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If I understood correctly, you need to get some element from medias

```
$artists = ORM::factory('artist')->find_all()->as_array();
$media = $artists[0]->media->find_all()->as_array(); // media of first artist
$name = $media[0]->name;
```

2) See above $artists is an array of ORM objects

Comment: No, I want to have all in one variable `$artists` (including media for each artist). But thanks for your answer, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, this is what I'd do.

```
class Model_Artist extends ORM {

    ///
    /// Whatever you have now
    ///

    private $_media_cache = NULL;

    public function media($key = NULL)
    {
        // Check cache
        if($this->_media_cache == NULL)
        {
            $this->_media_cache = $this->media->find_all();
        }

        if($key !== NULL)
        {
             // Use Arr::get in case index does not exist
             // Return empty media object when it does not exist so you can 
             // 'harmlessly' ask for its properties
             return Arr::get($this->_media_cache, $key, ORM::factory('Media'));
        }

        return $this->_media_cache;
    }
}
```

Callable as

```
$artists[0]->media(0)->name
```